# One page CRUD form operation (Laravel6)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have a table in my database with contact details. On my form, I have a Dropdown which displays the names of people, and which, once I click on the name, fills in the fields with the data (ajax).

The problem happens when I want to perform operations on the form data.

For example, I click on "M Bram Manu" (id = 1) in the Dropdown. My Ajax will fill out my form with the details of this contact.

But when I want to update, delete or add a new contact, it doesn't work properly.
So, if I click on "delete", it not delete the contact I choose but the last contact of the dropdown list. Why???

So I think my link retrieves the last ID from my dropdown, so I decided to put an hidden Input with the value of the contact ID that appears in the form. But I don't know how to retrieve this value to define it as the ID to send to the controller.

Dropdown bar and link button :

```
<form class="col-md-9">
        <label class="col-md-2">Rechercher : </label>
        <select class="form-control select2 col-md-7" id="selInscrit" name="selInscrit" onchange="selectID()">
            <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
            @foreach($inscrit as $inscrits)
            <option value="{{$inscrits->INS_ID}}">{{$inscrits->INS_CIVILITE}} {{$inscrits->INS_NOM}} {{$inscrits->INS_PREN}} {{$inscrits->INS_NUM_RUE}} {{$inscrits->INS_Rue}} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </form>




    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm col-md-3" role="group">
        <form action="" method="GET">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Edit</button>
        </form>


        <button type="submit" form="registerForm" formmethod="POST" formaction="{{ route('inscrits.store') }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" form="registerForm" formmethod="POST" formaction="{{ route('inscrits.update') }}" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Update</button>

        <form action="{{ route('inscrits.destroy') }}" method="POST">
        <input id="INS_ID" name="INS_ID" value="" type="hidden">        
        @method('DELETE')
        @csrf
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Delete </button>

        </form>           
    </div>
```

Ajax for dropdown :

```
<script>
$('#selInscrit').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = '{{ route("inscrits.show", ":id") }}';
    url = url.replace(':id', id);

    $.ajax({

        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response != null) {
                $('#INS_ID').val(response.INS_ID);
                $('#INS_CIVILITE').val(response.INS_CIVILITE);
                $('#INS_NOM').val(response.INS_NOM);
                $('#INS_PREN').val(response.INS_PREN);
                $('#INS_NAISS').val(response.INS_NAISS);
                $('#INS_AGE').val(response.INS_AGE);
                $('#INS_NUM_RUE').val(response.INS_NUM_RUE);
                $('#INS_Rue').val(response.INS_Rue);
                $('#INS_TEL1').val(response.INS_TEL1);
                $('#INS_OBS').val(response.INS_OBS);
                $('#INS_DATE').val(response.INS_DATE);
                $('#INS_TEL2').val(response.INS_TEL2);
            }

        }

    }); 
});
```

Route :

```
// INSCRITS

/ route for index
Route::get('/inscrits', 'InscritController@index')->name('inscrits.index');

// route for dropdown bar
Route::get('/inscrits/show/{id}', 'InscritController@show')->name('inscrits.show');

// route for update
// Route::match(['put', 'patch'], '/inscrits/update','InscritController@update')->name('inscrits.update');
Route::post('/inscrits/update','InscritController@update')->name('inscrits.update');
// route for store
Route::post('/inscrits/store', 'InscritController@store')->name('inscrits.store');

//route for delete
Route::delete('/inscrits/destroy', 'InscritController@destroy')->name('inscrits.destroy');
```

Form :

```
<form id="registerForm">
@csrf
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label for="INS_CIVILITE">Civilité</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_CIVILITE" name="INS_CIVILITE">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="Mme">Mme</option>
                <option value="Mlle">Mlle</option>
                <option value="M.">M.</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <label for="INS_NOM">Nom</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_NOM" name="INS_NOM" value=""  type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label for="INS_PREN">Prénom</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_PREN" name="INS_PREN" value=""  type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_NAISS">Année Naiss</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_NAISS" name="INS_NAISS" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_AGE">Age</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_AGE" name="INS_AGE" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
            <label for="INS_NUM_RUE"># Rue</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_NUM_RUE" name="INS_NUM_RUE" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <label for="INS_Rue">Libellé voie</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_Rue" name="INS_Rue">
                @foreach($rue as $rues)
                <option value="{{$rues->RUE_NUM}}">{{$rues->RUE_NOM}} ({{$rues->RUE_Type}})</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_TEL1">Téléphone 1</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_TEL1" name="INS_TEL1" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <label for="INS_OBS">Observation</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_OBS" name="INS_OBS" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_DATE">Date d'inscription</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_DATE" name="INS_DATE" value="" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label for="INS_TEL2">Téléphone 2</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="INS_TEL2" name="INS_TEL2" value="" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>

    <input id="INS_LIEU" name="INS_LIEU" value="WEB" type="hidden">
    <input id="INS_EID" name="INS_EID" value="" type="hidden">


</form>
```

The controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $inscrit = Inscrit::all();
    return view('index', compact('inscrit'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $storeData = $request->validate([
        'INS_CIVILITE' => 'max:15',
        'INS_NOM' => 'max:50',
        'INS_PREN' => 'max:50',
        'INS_NUM_RUE' => 'max:8',
        'INS_TEL1' => 'max:10',
        'INS_TEL2' => 'max:10',
        'INS_AGE' => 'numeric',
        'INS_OBS' => 'max:255',
        'INS_Rue' => 'max:255',
        'INS_DATE' => 'max:255',
        'INS_NAISS' => 'max:255',
    ]);
    $inscrit = Inscrit::create($storeData);

    return redirect('/inscrits')->with('completed', 'Nouvel inscrit !');
}

public function show($id = 0)
{
    $data = Inscrit::where('INS_ID', $id)->first();
    return response()->json($data);
}

    public function edit($id)
{
    $inscrit = Inscrit::findOrFail($id);
    return view('index', compact('inscrit'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $updateData = $request->validate([
        'INS_CIVILITE' => 'max:15',
        'INS_NOM' => 'max:50',
        'INS_PREN' => 'max:50',
        'INS_NUM_RUE' => 'max:8',
        'INS_TEL1' => 'max:10',
        'INS_TEL2' => 'max:10',
        'INS_AGE' => 'numeric',
        'INS_OBS' => 'max:255',
        'INS_Rue' => 'max:255',
        'INS_DATE' => 'max:255',
        'INS_NAISS' => 'max:255',
    ]);
    $id = request()->input('INS_EID');
    Inscrit::where('INS_ID', $id)->update($updateData);
    return redirect('/inscrits')->with('completed', 'inscrit mis à jour');
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $id = request()->input('INS_ID');
    $inscrit = Inscrit::where('INS_ID', $id)->delete();

    return redirect('/inscrits')->with('completed', 'inscrit supprimé');
}
```

[The form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiHcr.png)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0Hx2.png)

Comment: If you need to get all form datas you just can to do it : $form_datas = $request->all
And after make something like this : $form_datas['INS_CIVILITE']  for exemple
Is that your question ?

Comment: And where I put this? In the href of the save link for example?

Comment: My question is: How to ask properly my controller "Hey, I want to save/upgrade/delete the contact inside the form!"

Comment: before controller : use App\Inscrit
in controller : Inscrit::where('Id', $id)->update($updateData); ??

Comment: example : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

 DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $user->id)
                ->update(['active' => true]);

Comment: $request is in your update function

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the ID sent to the controller isn't the ID of the contact in the form but the last ID of the dropdown... and this is the problem!

Comment: Before to create the update method 
Create the edit one 
To check send the id in your route and after that you could to get it in your update function

Comment: Do you put your buttons inside the for loop ?

Comment: base on your code, your buttons are outside the for loop, then it's impossible for you to get the selected id to delete edit and update

Comment: I just want 3 buttons on side, not 3 buttons in every option of the dropdown!

Comment: Maybe some JS can help me to take the selected id, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
public function edit ($id) {
        $inscritContent = Inscrit::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();
        return view('admin.inscrit.edit.form', [
            'content' => $iscritContent
        ]);
    }

    public function update($id, Request $req) {
        $inscrit = Inscrit::findOrFail($id);
        $inscrit->update($req->all());
        return redirect(route('admin.inscrit.index'));
    }
```

admin.inscrit.edit.form and admin.inscrit.index are blade template

Comment: I have an edit method (I add it in controller section of this question). But I can't have 2 templates, I need to do all of the CRUD operations in the same form of the same page!

Comment: this is not a problem you can make it in the same template (redirect and view to the same blade)

Comment: In your blade you can juste make a hidden input with 
id value as value="{{$content->id}}"
Or just send all contacts in your blade and make a foreach loop and each contact will have an hidden input id ;)

Comment: So I need an edit button, click on it, edit my field, and click on a other update button? Ok, but how I code the "href" of the button or link? Because I still have this ID problem...

Comment: In the foreach loop of the dropdown bar, the contact ID "INS_ID" is the value of the <option>. So this is THIS value I want to take... .

Comment: I already told you 
You can keep the same page if you wish 
But you need to send all contact from controller to blade and make a loop with all contact. and just add an hidden input inside with ID value (example : value="$contact->id") 
Each value get an id so you'll catch in your update function (with $req->all in a variable like $form_datas["id"] because the name of input in your blade is ID
You're copy ?

Comment: Send all contact from controller to blade, like this (in controller) : `public function index()
    {
        $inscrit = Inscrit::all();
        return view('index', compact('inscrit'));
    }`

Comment: It's my first Laravel project, so I am a little bit confused, but ok, I try this

Comment: A CRUD example as you need : https://github.com/LucasLaurens/Laravel_CRUD

Comment: I try all of this, and the ID sent to the controller is always the last ID of the loop and not the ID selected. If I want to delete the contact I select, it delete the last contact of the loop for example. Maybe I need to send all contact from controller to blade, but not the entire blade, idk...

Comment: For "edit" the error is different: Trying to get property 'INS_ID' of non-object.

Comment: Can you send me your repo ?

Comment: I don't have repo. But it begin to work, my save button do the job, so I need to focus on delete and update now. (I update my code here)

Comment: It works! The problem was mainly due to a bad writing of the links of the buttons and a bad recovery of the ID in the controller.